# Restart the SMTP service after reboot

Tags: smtp, service

I am working on a 2008 R2 File server patching, the SMTP service is in Automatic mode but after I get the reboot done it switches to the manual mode and moves to stooped state.

How can start the the service with a script or is there any way that it will stick to automatic mode

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script where you call

```
sc start smtpsvc
```

This will start the SMTP service.

But i it sounds like you may have some configuration issue etc. with it. I suggest that you check the configuration and also logs in case there are some errors.

Comment: Actually i am not aware of the configuration weather it is active passive or something else and there are couple of servers, so we need to get all the details if the service is stopped on server then what is the cause of the that